# Resending intent fails due to missing permission on URI

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my app all activities are login-protected:
Each activity checks in its `onCreate`/`onShow`-callback whether the user is logged in. If so, nothing special happens. But if the user is not logged in, then these callbacks redirect the user to a `LoginActivity` and finish the current activity:

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
loginIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT, getIntent());
finish();
startActivity(loginIntent);
```

As the lines above show, the original `Intent` used to start the current activity is added to the `loginIntent`'s extras. Thus, the `LoginActivity` can resend the `Intent` after successfull login ... in theory. However, that does not always work.

It works when started from the launcher:

```
Intent with ACTION_MAIN --> MainActivity --> Redirect to LoginActivity -->
Redirect back to MainActivity after successful login
```

It does not work when using the share-button on Chrome:

```
Intent with ACTION_SEND --> SendActivity --> Redirect to LoginActivity -->
Redirect back to SendActivity after successful login
```

The problem is the last redirect which tries to resend the original `Intent` which was used to initially start the `SendActivity`:

```
// Resend original intent
startActivity((Intent) getIntent().getExtra(EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT));
```

It fails with an Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10075 does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/6471932623902346234.jpg
```

**And now my question:

How can I resend the `Intent` without causing that permission exception?

How can I pass the required permissions?**

---

NOTE:
I really want that redirect-behavior with finishing the current activity and resending the `Intent`. It is not an option to simply keep the activities (`MainActivity`, `SendActivity`) on the stack and return to them from the `LoginActivity` for various reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resending the original `Intent` in the `LoginActivity` works if the permissions are passed along the `Activity`/`Intent` chain. This can be achieved by:

1. The redirect-`Intents` are copies of the original `Intent`.
2. Before resending, the `Intent` is made explicit.

For example `SomeActivity` redirects to `LoginActivity` using a copy of the `Intent` that was used to start `SomeActivity`:

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getIntent()); // copy ...
loginIntent.setClass(this, LoginActivity.class); // ... explicit now
// maybe loginIntent.setAction(...) etc.
loginIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT, getIntent());
finish();
startActivity(loginIntent);
```

Now, after successful login, `LoginActivity` can redirect back to `SomeActivity`:

```
Intent origIntent = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT);
Intent redirectIntent = new Intent(origIntent); // copy ...
redirectIntent.setClass(this, SomeActivity.class); // ... explicit now
finish();
startActivity(redirectIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you are missing is `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`.

When you get a `Uri` from an outside party (e.g., `EXTRA_STREAM` on `ACTION_SEND`), you should be granted permission to at least read the content identified by that `Uri`. That in itself [is a bit tricky to set up](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html).

However, that permission grant is only to the component that receives the `Intent` (e.g., your activity that responded to `ACTION_SEND`). If you try delegating the work to anything else (another activity, a service, etc.), that component will not have permission.

So, you have a few options:

One would be to convert your authentication/authorization stuff into a fragment or other bit of UI that can be used *in situ*, instead of starting another activity. This would allow you to keep the user all in one place, and that place has read access to the content.

Another would be to consume the content before redirecting the user to the `LoginActivity`.

Another would be to not `finish()` the original activity, and use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` for `LoginActivity` to bring the existing instance of the original activity back to the foreground. In theory, it should still have read access to the content. Your problem is coming from the fact that you are destroying the original instance and creating a fresh one, and the fresh one has no read access.

Yet another approach would be to try adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on both the `LoginActivity` `Intent` and, later, the `Intent` that you are passing via the `EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT` extra. My guess is that this will not work.

A variation on the above theme would be to not only put the original `Intent` in `EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT`, but also extract its `Uri` and stuff that in the data facet of the `LoginActivity` `Intent`:

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
loginIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT, getIntent());
loginIntent.setData(getIntent().getData());
loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

`LoginActivity` probably would still need to also call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on the `Intent` from `EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT`.

Basically, in the latter scenarios, what you want is for your original activity to grant read access to `LoginActivity`, solely so that `LoginActivity` can grant read access back to the new instance of the original activity.

In the end, whatever instance of the original activity that you use needs to have read access to the content, and it's up to you to ensure that the instance has that access, given that you were granted access to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I already played around with the grant-flags and setting the data/extras explicitly. But it didn't work. However I think I figured out how resending intents works. Now, when redirecting I "convert" the intent to an explicit intent by setting the correct target activity class, for example `SendActivity`. It seems that I am not allowed to resend this implicit intent, but the explicit intent works as expected. That's what I wanted to do anyway ;-)